# Click on check box after confirming text in html table which is dynamic

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I need to click on the check box in the HTML table after asserting the text. Below is the html.

```
<div class="k-widget k-grid ">
    <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding: 0px 16px 0px 0px;">
        <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="50px">
                    <col>
                    <col>
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th aria-sort="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="k-header checkbox-grid-column"><input id="c3c07f7e-5119-4a36-9f67-98fa4d21fa07" type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="c3c07f7e-5119-4a36-9f67-98fa4d21fa07"></label></th>
                        <th aria-sort="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="k-header"><a class="k-link">Permission</a></th>
                        <th aria-sort="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="k-header"><a class="k-link">Description</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-grid-container">
        <div class="k-grid-content k-virtual-content">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <table tabindex="-1" class="k-grid-table">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="50px">
                        <col>
                        <col>
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="k-master-row">
                            <td colspan="1" class="checkbox-grid-column"><input id="c8711bab-702a-43b9-8a75-02ad06a8baa3" type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="c8711bab-702a-43b9-8a75-02ad06a8baa3"></label></td>
                            <td>ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE</td>
                            <td colspan="1">Enable Bulk Delete button in access group management</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="k-master-row k-alt">
                            <td colspan="1" class="checkbox-grid-column"><input id="a029bc1e-53d8-4328-89ce-6640363d515a" type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="a029bc1e-53d8-4328-89ce-6640363d515a"></label></td>
                            <td>ACCESSGROUP_DELETE</td>
                            <td colspan="1">Enable Delete Button in the access group details page</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="k-master-row">
                            <td colspan="1" class="checkbox-grid-column"><input id="645f8474-9840-48e2-a02c-112178aaf5e2" type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="645f8474-9840-48e2-a02c-112178aaf5e2"></label></td>
                            <td>ACCESSGROUP_NEW</td>
```

I was able to get text from the TR with the code mentioned

```
table_id = context.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]//table//tbody//tr//td[1]')
    print (table_id)
    # get all of the rows in the table
    #rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    #for row in rows:
        #permission = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')[1]
        #print (permission.text)
```

But I need to iterate through and find exact text and then click the check box.

Comment: What text are you looking for? Which `INPUT` do you want to click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily click on the associated *check box* with respect to the desired text e.g. `ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE`, `ACCESSGROUP_DELETE`, `ACCESSGROUP_NEW`, etc writing a function as follows:

```
def click_item(item_text):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[.='" + item_text + "']//preceding::td[1]//label[@for]"))).click()
```

Now you can call the function passing any of the labels as a string arguments as follows:

```
click_item("ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE")
# or
click_item("ACCESSGROUP_DELETE")
# or
click_item("ACCESSGROUP_NEW")
```

Comment: works like a charm thank you so much will start paying attention on learning to make better CSS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The locator that you want is an XPath because XPath lets you find an element based on contained text.

```
//tr[./td[.='ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE']]//input
^ find a TR
    ^ that has a child TD that contains the desired text
                                      ^ then find the descendant INPUT of that TR
```

You can replace the 'ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE' text with whichever label you want in the table. I would take this a step further and put this into a method and pass in the label text as a parameter so you can make it reusable.

Comment: i am able to get this and replace it in a method as the text can be dynamic and fetched from data sheet, the main concern is to clock on checked box which is in same TD on [0] index

Comment: So basically after asserting the text have to click on check box which is on same row on 0 index

Comment: That's what this does. If the text doesn't exist on the page, the element won't be found... that's the assert part. All you need to do is to click the `INPUT` element returned by this locator, which is your desired checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate the relevant checkbox which corresponds to some given text use the following expression:

```
//td[text()='ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE']/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

Demo:

[image]

In the above expression

- [`preceding-sibling` is XPath Axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) which matches all "siblings" - [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) elements having the same parent and appearing above the current element.
- [`text()` is the XPath Function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) which returns the text content of the current node

Answer (score -1):

Below is code in java....you can relate it with Python. Hope this helps

```
String rowXpath = "//*[@id='root']//table//tbody//tr[INDEX]" //xpath to find no of rows
noOfRows = context.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']//table//tbody//tr") //get the count of row

for(int i=1; i<= noOfRows; i++){


    String currXpath = rowXpath.replace(INDEX, i) //update xpath to point to curent row
    currXpath = currXpath+/td[2] //Find xpath of chkBox for current tr in loop

    String chkBoxXpath = currXpath+"/td[1]" //xpath to point to 1st td under current tr in loop

    String currentText = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, currXpath).getText(); //find text in 2nd td current row in loop

    if(currentText.equals("ACCESSGROUP_BULKDELETE")){ //Compare with any text of your interest //chk if text found above macthes with your interested text 
        context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, chkBoxXpath).click(); //click on the 1st td(chkbox) for the  tr which contains your text
    }
}
```